# Prisma - Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `Application_jobId_fkey (index)`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prisma

Why am I allowed to delete an entry from `Applicant`, but not from `Job` (or `User`)?

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("DATABASE_URL") // using the local database as a shadow database
}

// General User Model
model User {
  id        String     @unique @id @default(uuid())
  email     String     @unique
  name      String?
  username  String?
  password  String
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt
  employer  Employer?
  applicant Applicant?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model Job {
  id           String        @id @default(uuid())
  title        String
  description  String
  company      Company?      @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId    String?
  employer     Employer?      @relation(fields: [employerId], references: [id])
  employerId   String?
  companyURL   String?
  skills       String[]
  status       String        @default("open")
  initialPrice Int           @default(0)
  createdAt    DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime      @updatedAt
  applications Application[]
}

model Application {
  id          String    @id @default(uuid())
  job         Job       @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id])
  jobId       String
  applicant   Applicant @relation(fields: [applicantId], references: [id])
  applicantId String    
  start_date  String
  interview_date String
  gig_price   Int
  payment_method String
  additionalDocumentURL String?
  cover_letter String
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
}

model Company {
  id          String     @id @default(uuid())
  name        String
  description String
  location    String
  jobs        Job[]
  empolyers   Employer[]
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
}

model Employer {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String   @unique
  company   Company?  @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId String?
  jobs      Job[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Applicant {
  id           String        @id @default(uuid())
  user         User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       String        @unique
  createdAt    DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime      @updatedAt
  applications Application[]
  cv String? 
}


model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String 
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}
```

If I attempt to delete an entry from `Job`, I get the following

```
Type: undefined
Message: 
Invalid `prisma.job.delete()` invocation:


Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `Application_jobId_fkey (index)`

Code: P2003

Query:
[object Object]
```